# command 'sam' not found using sudo

Tags: amazon-web-services, unix, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed sam using following

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install-linux.html

I can run following

```
sam build
```

But not

```
sudo sam build 
which gives me => sudo: sam: command not found
```

Further going I have found that I need to sudo permission to sudo as follows.

```
sudo env "PATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/sam" sam
```

Is the above correct? I haven't run this command and not sure if it is proper.

This is what I have run.

```
test -d ~/.linuxbrew && eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
test -d /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
test -r ~/.bash_profile && echo "eval \$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)" >>~/.bash_profile
echo "eval \$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)" >>~/.profile
```

Comment: Why do you need to sudo with SAM? Typically there would be no need to do this, and it's a bad thing to use sudo if you really don't need it.

Comment: @jarmod, I now do not use sudo unless it is required. The question is old.

Comment: Makes sense. I was primarily adding that info for future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:
In a normal terminal (normal user):

```
which sam
```

This will give you the location, where `sam` is installed, let's say `/somewhere/bin/sam`.

Then: try:

```
sudo /somewhere/bin/sam build
```

Answer (score 3):

if you followed the tutorial about Linux+Brew+SAM install, maybe you forgot to run the command:
`brew install aws-sam-cli`

Or just make an alias to the command

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

add row at the end

```
alias sam='/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/sam'
```

Save. Restart terminal.

Answer (score 1):

`pip3 install aws-sam-cli`

this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command after following the official [aws sam cli installation tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install-linux.html)

```
$ brew install aws-sam-cli

==> Installing aws-sam-cli from aws/tap
==> Downloading https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-
...
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.13.2: 3,899 files, 91MB
```

At the end it will show where it would be installed.
for me it is the path
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.13.2/libexec/bin/sam

then make a symbolic link

```
$ ln -s /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.13.2/libexec/bin/sam /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/sam
```

now you will be able to call sam easily

```
$ sam --version
SAM CLI, version 1.13.2
```